# jQuery not working in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to print html data `result` on page using

```
$("#regerror").html(result);
```

which doesn't work. But doing it using plain javascript works

```
document.getElementById("regerror").innerHTML = result;
```

I working with Django. This is how I have included the library in the base template.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}base.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you have jquery loaded to the page ?

Comment: Has the jQuery library been included in your `head` tag?

Comment: Do you have jquery on the page? Seems like you don't. Are there any errors in javascript console?

Comment: More info... what kind of element? what's in result? can you provide a working example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: my javascript code is in base.js file

Answer (score 1):

You most likely forgot or incorrectly linked the JQuery library or you're calling it before the library has been loaded.

[Here's a standalone](http://jsfiddle.net/96qC6/) showing you that it does in fact work.

This is the current version

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Here's a plain example

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "whatever.html",
        success: function(result){
            $("#results").html(result);
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div id="results"></div>
```

<sub>[RTFM...](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works)</sub>